# How to integrate reactjs in shopify theme

Tags: reactjs, shopify

I am using Quickshot Shopify theme development tool.And downloaded theme locally on my system.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can easily integrate React in shopify theme. Here is great [tutorial to integrate React with shopify theme.](https://www.cadence-labs.com/2019/12/how-to-add-react-to-a-shopify-theme/)